# Particular solution of $r^2y'' + 2ry' - 6y = -ar^2$ when finite at 0

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to find a specific solution for  the ODE: $$r^2y'' + 2ry' - 6y = -ar^2$$
with a being a positive constant. The complementary solution I have found is $$y^h=c_1r^2+c_2/r^3$$
but in this case, I know that $c_2 = 0$ because the solution is known to be finite at $r=0$, so that $$y^h=c_1r^2$$
However, I cannot seem to be able to find a complementary solution. Using an online ODE solver that does not offer step by step instructions, I found that the particular solution is
$$-\frac{ar^2\ln \left(r\right)}{5}+\frac{ar^2}{25}$$
but this solution is problematic since it results in $y$ not being finite at $r=0$.

I would really appreciate some further insight on obtaining the particular solution of this ODE

Comment: The solution from the ODE solver *is* finite near $r=0$

Comment: That's true, I got really confused there. Still, do you happen to know how the particular solution is derived?

Comment: When the homogeneous solution is exponentials and the particular solution is linearly dependent on the homogeneous solutions, you add a polynomial prefactor of the smallest possible degree before you use the method of undetermined coefficients. When the homogeneous solutions are monomials as they are here, and the particular solution is linearly dependent on the homogeneous solutions, you multiply a prefactor of $(\ln r)^m$ where $m$ is the smallest possible degree that makes the particular solution linearly independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $y_h(r) = \frac{c_1}{r^3}$, assuming as a particular solution

$$
y_p = \frac{c_1(r)}{r^3}
$$

(Variation of constants method) after substitution we have

$$
r c''_1(r)-4c'_1(r)+ar^4=0
$$

now calling $u(r) = c_1'(r)$ we follow with

$$
r u'(r) - 4u(r) + a r^4 = 0
$$

here $u_h(r)$ is easily obtained giving

$$
u_h(r) = c_2 r^4
$$

now applying the same procedure making $u_p(r) = c_2(r)r^4$ and substituting we obtain easily

$$
u(r) = c_2r^4-a r^4\ln r = c'_1(r)
$$

and after integration we have

$$
c_1(r) = \frac{a r^5}{25}-\frac{1}{5} a r^5 \ln (r)+\frac{c_2 r^5}{5}
$$

and finally choosing $c_2=0$ (it is a particular solution)

$$
y_p(r) = \frac{c_1(r)}{r^3} = \left(\frac{a r^5}{25}-\frac{1}{5} a r^5 \ln (r)\right)\frac{c_1}{r^3}
$$